# How do you find out EmailTemplate selected in Case or EmailMessage

Tags: email-template, email2case

Is there a way to find out what `Template` user selected when sending an email? I was looking at it in the `EmailTemplate` object field called `TemplateType` this will give you either `Text' or`Visualforce` etc... but how would you have a reference to EmailMessage or Case from EmailTemplate?

I'm after finding out which EmailTemplate user have selected while sending an email?

I do not see any reference between EmailTemplate/EmailMessage and Case object

Is there a better way to find out? or have reference?

Comment: do you know whether there are any updates to this, a year and a half after? How did you solve your problem?

Comment: I don't remember its been so long, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this asked of me a few times, and the best way I've found is to embed some sort of unique identifier in the template itself. If you're using HTML templates, you can make the identifier less visible or totally invisible. If you're using text templates, your identifier will be visible. In both cases, your user could potentially delete your identifier if they edit the message before sending it.

`EmailMessage` doesn't have any sort of relationship to `EmailTemplate` outside of its content.

Comment: I'm using Visualforce template is that the only option?

Comment: Same holds true with a Visualforce template. One advantage is your users don't get to edit the email before sending it if they're using a VF template.